# Primitive undefined notions in first-order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

Correct me in my following understanding of why I consider the following (in bold and italics) to be primitive undefined notions.

1. Variables stand for the ***mathematical objects*** that base the theory. Proper axioms tell us *not* what they “are”, but what we can “do” with them.
2. ***Functions and relations*** connecting the mathematical objects. Like addition and multiplication in linear algebra are *described* by the axioms. Similarly, belonging is also a primitive in set theory. Equality is also described by equality axioms.
3. ***One of existential or universal quantifier*** cuz the one can be defined in terms of the other via connectives.
4. For connectives I’m unsure. Because I think they can be “defined” using truth tables.

Comment: You have to start with the language : symbols, expressions (i.e. strings of symbols), terms and formulas.

Comment: The primitives are the symbols: quantifiers, connectives, individual variables, predicate and function symbols (plus equality : $=$ in FOL with equality). And the logical axioms governing them.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA suppose you say that $\exists$ is a primitive. Will you still say that $\forall$ is also a primitive? I don’t think so. Coz I can *define* $\forall$ via $\exists$ and $\lnot$.